# meaning of the file extension, core data, iphone

Tags: iphone, core-data

My question : I would like to know the semantic of 2 file extension in core data and what are the content in each of them and when we should use them

```
1.myFileName.momd ( or myFileName.mom )
2.myFileName.sqlite
```

I am a beginner for core data programming. Please advice me on this issue. All comments are welcomed here
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The extension `.mom` or `.momd` is an [Apple model file](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreDataVersioning/Articles/vmModelFormat.html).

The extension `.sqlite` indicates an [SQLite database](http://www.filefacts.net/sqlite-file-extension).

Use either of them when your file is the appropriate type for that extension. (IOW, use the `.mom` extension when  your file is an Apple model file.)